# Assigning x values to plot vector

Tags: r, vector, indexing, label, assign

I have a vector

```
y = c ( -0.04691190 , 0.11711564 , -0.31075813 , 0.17097441 , 0.19852150 , 0.09417714 , -0.19460248 , 0.11151099 , 1.02124982 , NA , -0.20645774 , -0.25385414)
```

that I would like to plot with each value on the y axis. I would like their corresponding x values to be the cube root of their index, i.e. y[1]'s x value is 1, y[2]'s x value is 2^(1/3) and so on. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Do:

```
plot(seq_along(y)^(1/3), y)
```